# Launch file with xacro parameter

Tags: roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have some problem in simulating multi-robot systems in Gazebo/ROS. The problem is in the topic name since every robot subscribes to the same topic (e.g. for a laser in base_scan/scan). I would like to pretag it (e.g. robotname/base_scan/scan).
Is there anyone with the same problem?
I already tried with xacro, i.e. I create a tag of my robot (including the canonical link) but the launch file seems that does not like a macro initialization in it.
Any other suggestions?
Thank you for your time,

Marco

P.S. IF it could help, my launch file looks like this

```
<node name="spawn_kh31" 
  pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
  args="-urdf -param robot_file -model robot1 -x 0 -y 0 -z 0.2"
  respawn="false" output="screen"
/>
```

This is the version not using the macro file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32389/launch-file-with-xacro-parameter/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find everything here: http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1